# Тренировка для linux админа

Tags: linux, iso-образ

Встречал ли кто в сети образы "битых" linux систем? Т.е. такая себе тренировка - получаем нерабочий, специально или намеренно образ и ковыряем его до полного восстановления - уверен, что читал про такой портал - но вот как обычно не закинул в закладки - если кто знает поделитесь пожалуста.Заранее спосибо.

Comment: Нужно было сразу указать - что работаю больше 5 лет по профессии и опыт и практика "с нуля" у меня есть и экзамены у меня есть сданные у буржуев (rhcsa, lpi) - однако на работах пока что тишина - вот зачем нужна практика. А ищу именно тот ресурс, который и описал.

Comment: Кажется на yandex олимпиаде давали что-то похожее, не оно случайно?

Comment: ага - но вот самих заданий и образов я что-то не нашёл

Answer (score 2):

Ломать не строить, сделать просто же..

p.s. для того чтобы починить "что-то", нужно знать как это "с нуля" настроить.. Т.е. вам нужно не починять поломанное, а поднимать самому - это лучшая практика.

А вот когда пойдете сдавать экзамены у буржуев, вот тогда они вам дадут поломанные системы и вы, умея поставить их с нуля, восстановите без проблем. Но есть в этом подводный камень, который я вам пока не скажу :-D

Answer (score 1):

Поищи в инете sexlinux, ну или ггенту снуля поднять. после того, как научишься ее настраивать полностью, в том числе и гуй -- с любым другим дистром проблем не возникнет... проверено на совственном опыте :)